# I need to input 20 numbers and to output only double location

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

try to input 20 numbers with array and to output
the numbers in the double location only but somehow it's print 
also the 0 location... please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define n 20
int main()
{
int num[n]={0},i=0,order=1,double_locaion=0;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
printf("please enter %d number\n",order);
scanf("%d",&num[i]);
order++;
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if (i%2==0 && i!=1 && i!=0)
    {
        printf("%d\n",num[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in the double location" and `double_locaion`? The latter is not used in the code.

Comment: Why use `order`? `i` was already there.

Comment: I need to print the double location in num[i]

Comment: What does double location mean?

Comment: @SouravGhosh  because i want to start the %d from 1

Comment: Hmmm..I guess double location is even count for the numbers, that's the odd indexes....

Comment: He's clearly talking about the even numbers.

Comment: @SouravGhosh even locaion like num[2], num[4]...

Comment: @alondavidi you know `num[2]` is the _3rd_ element...right?

Comment: @joemartin94 I wouldn't say clearly but now that OP has mentioned it I guess it makes sense.

Comment: Please show your input, expected output, and actual output.  Then we can better understand your intention.

Comment: Like input 3 0  30 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 0  3 0  3 0  30 3 0 3
And output only the 3

Comment: Aah, you're thinking of "every second element", that's where "double location" comes from, right? I'm not native either, just trying to understand.

Comment: Update your question with this information.  Be sure to include the *expected* and *actual* output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, start with 2 and increase by 2 every time, the you don't have to deal with 0th element and odd element.

```
for (i = 2; i < n; i += 2)
{
    printf("%d\n",num[i]);
}
```

Comment: explanation, please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no way that your code is printing the `0-th` location of the array. That's *impossible* given the condition of the `if` statement.

Secondly `n`- you don;t need to use macro expansion for that name.

```
/* This program takes 20 integer number from input.
 * Prints the numbers entered in odd positions.(First,Third,..etc).
 */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define NUM 20
int main(void)
{
    int numArr[NUM];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        printf("please enter %zu number\n",i+1);
        if( scanf("%d",&numArr[i]) != 1){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in input" );
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if( i%2 == 0 )// if you want to omit the first number put the 
                      // the condition (i%2 == 0 && i)
        {
            printf("%d\n",numArr[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### What you did wrong that your code skipped 0th element?

```
if (i%2==0 && i!=1 && i!=0)
                      ^^^^
```

`i` when `0` makes this condition false - and you never get to print it.

#### `i!=1` ?

If `i=1` then `i%2` will be `1`, so you will not even check the second conditions, the whole conditional expression will become false. So you can safely omit this logic.

#### Is there a better way?

Sure,

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i += 2){
    printf("%d\n",num[i]);
}
```

#### Explanation

If you consider that every time you check the modular arithmetic of `2` the elements which results to `0` remained are

```
 0,2,4,6,8,10,...18
```

See the pattern? Starts with `0` and increments by `2` each time and when does it stop? Yes before reaching `20` coding it we get

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i += 2){ 
/*   Initialize with i=0 as first number is 0 (i=0)
 *   Increments by 2 (i+=2) 
 *   Runs when less than 20 (i<n) 
 */
    printf("%d\n",num[i]);
}
```

If you want to omit the 0-th index do initialize properly

```
for(size_t i = 2; i < n; i += 2){
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want the numbers from array that are present at even position than you can do like this:

```
for (i = 2; i < n; i=i + 2) //Initialize i = 0 if 0 is consider as even
{
    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}
```

I above code i is initialized to 2 and the increment in each iteration is 2 so it will access elements only at even position (2,4,6...).

Comment: Ok and what with the zero element?

Comment: you want to print zero index element too?, if so then just initialize  i=0;